# Hide DataGridTemplateColumn based on Property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` with several `DataGridTemplateColumn`s.

The definition of the `DataGrid` looks like:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedFolder.Documents, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDocument, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Filename" Width="*" SortMemberPath="Titel">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Titel}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Format" Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="Extension">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Extension}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Created" Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="DateCreated">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding DateCreated, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="User" Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="CreationUser">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding CreationUser, Converter={StaticResource UserIdToUserNameConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete" Width="Auto" Visibility="{Binding DataContext.User.Permission, Converter={StaticResource UserPermissionToDeleteVisibility}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" Command="{Binding DataContext.DialogActionCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                            CommandParameter="{x:Static helper:ButtonActionTarget.DeleteDocument}" Width="24" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image Source="{x:Static helper:ImageHelper.Delete}"/>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The data is updated correctly. Unfortunately the `Visibility` of the last column is not applied correctly. What am I doing wrong here? My converter is not called any time.

The converter looks like:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value is UserPermission)
    {
        if ((((UserPermission)value) & UserPermission.Delete) == UserPermission.Delete)
            return Visibility.Visible;
    }
    return Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

If I set the `Visibility`-Property on the `Button` in the `DataGridTemplateColumnt` it works. But I want the complete column to be hidden.

Comment: is there any data binding error? and the  property `User.Permission` is notifying changes?

Comment: I get the error: `Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.User.Permission; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridTemplateColumn' (HashCode=4155109); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')`  
User.Permission is not NotifyChanged, but it should only be used one time

Comment: the main error is binding. is there a window as root element of the data grid? perhaps try `AncestorType=DataGrid`. if does not work then could you post the full xaml?